# What's wrong with this non digits only slug regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a pattern match for slugs, these would be alphanumeric sequences hyphen separated.

They can be:

- Number starting or ended, but not only digits
- Can also be only alphabetic
- Can also can be only one word

I got `/[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$/` which almost works but it'll match.  `3` or `10`

For example:

- *2020-best-year-of-world* should match
- *best-of-world* should match
- *best-of-2021* should match
- *2021* should not match

I leave here a [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/UC4XzD/1/) with my test

Comment: `/3` is Number starting or ending (ending in case), and it is not only digit... Are you sure it is incorrect?

Comment: Right I just edited to make it clear

Comment: What about `2021-2022`? What about `this------slug`? What about `this-`?

Comment: I came up with this: `/[a-z0-9]+(-*[a-z])+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$`. Would that do the trick for you?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado What about a single-character slug, like `a`? There was no minimum length requirement of 2 characters stated in the question.

Comment: @TomLord I've came up with `[a-z0-9]*(-*[a-z])+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$` that would accept single-char. I've also edited my answer with that. Thanks for noticing it!

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado What about `----a`? Your regex allows this, but I think it shouldn't. OP didn't make it clear whether the slug must start with an alphanumeric character, or whether multiple consecutive hyphens are disallowed,  but my expectation is that's the desire. Also, what about `12-34-ab` or `12-34ab`? Your regex definitely disallows these incorrectly.

Comment: In short, I don't think you can solve this in a single regex, without using a look-ahead.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from adding an anchor `^` to assert the start of the steing, you can add a negative lookahead to not only match digits, or else your pattern will also match only 2020.

```
^(?![\d]+$)[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![\d]+$)` Negative lookahead, assert not only hyphens and digits to the right
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ occurrences of a-z or 0-9
- `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat the previous pattern preceded by `-`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZvoC6E/1)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
[a-z0-9]*(-*[a-z])+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

- It starts with a char or a number
- It needs to contain char or `-` in the middle (the part I've added from your regex, in order to filter only digit)
- Ends with char, digit

I wasn't sure if, for instance 2020-2021 should match. If it shouldn't, you should do an small edit on the middle part...

I've tested [in the same tool you suggested](https://regex101.com/r/WqBiKm/2)

---

EDIT: Fixed regex to accept single characters, as suggested by [Tom Lord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69273579/whats-wrong-with-this-non-digits-only-slug-regex?noredirect=1#comment122458093_69273579)